# How can I dockerize my springboot application which has multiple datasources?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a springboot application which uses a postgresql database and a mongoDB database , I have been able to correctly configure them but now when I want to dockerize my application to later deploy it on a Kubernetes cluster, I am completely clueless. Most of the youtube tutorials and articles are on how to dockerize simple springboot applications or springboot applications that use only one database, thus any input on how I can proceed to dockerize my application would be really appreciated!

Edit:
I am following this tutorial -
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/running-a-multi-container-springboot-postgresql-application-with-docker-compose/

Here in the docker-compose.yml file-

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  API:
    image: 'blog-api-docker.jar'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      PostgreSQL:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  PostgreSQL:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

Only one postgreSQL datasource is defined ,in my project with a similar postgreSQL datasource as given in the tutorial I am also using a mongoDB database which is running on atlas.
I am also including my application.properties file for your reference-

```
    spring.ds-psql.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/devicestatspsql
    spring.ds-psql.datasource.username=
    spring.ds-psql.datasource.password=
    
    spring.data.mongodb.users-mongo-atlas.uri=*mongodb database url here*

    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

So I just need to know what changes are required in my docker-compose.yml file to accommodate this mongodb database in the docker image

Comment: Can you explain why you think dockerizing an application with two data sources would be different to an application with one?

Comment: First of all I am a complete beginner in docker, and the only reason why I asked this question was because I have no idea where to start, should I use docker-compose? and if yes then how will my docker-compose.yml file differ from a single database springboot application? Also apologies if my question seemed too dumb or insignificant, as I said I am an absolute beginner and currently completely clueless on how I can proceed!

Comment: No need to apologize, I wasn't implying anything with the question. Any tutorials you follow to deploy a simple spring boot app in a docker container should be applicable to an app with multiple data sources.

Comment: I have edited the question and have specified the tutorial that I am following , if possible please look into it and suggest some solution.

Comment: If you are using the atlas cloud service you probably don't need anything in your docker-compose file. As long as your spring boot container has network connectivity it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kubernetes [**Configmap**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) and [**Secret**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) as of now to store the configuration of your application.

Configmap and Secret are mostly for storing configurations like database connection strings, usernames, and passwords.

You can create different configuration maps as per requirement for Dev,Stag and Prod then inject the specific to your deployment so the application will get those values from either `.env` file or from `OS environment`.

Here's the reference [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, although I am also facing problems on how I can proceed with docker on my springboot application , it has multiple datasources and I dont know how I can create my docker-compose.yml file for the same, as in how it would be different from a single database springboot application?

Comment: Feel free to post new question with details and clarity what actually you are location how the code taking two data sources. And feel free to update the status of question if answer you question or do upvote if found it helpful.

Comment: Post new question with details and tutorial you are following so that would be helpful for others to answers instead we start discussion in comment.

Comment: I have edited the question and have put in the necessary details , if possible please look into it and suggest how can I proceed with the same.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265491/when-to-re-post-a-question

Comment: I have reposted the question with the edits here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726486/i-need-to-dockerize-my-springboot-application-which-has-multiple-datasources

Comment: thanks, that would be helpful for others to answer and feel free to update the status of question if answers your question.