# I need to dockerize my springboot application which has multiple datasources

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a springboot application which uses a postgresql database and a mongoDB database , I have been able to correctly configure them but now when I want to dockerize my application to later deploy it on a Kubernetes cluster, I am completely clueless. Most of the youtube tutorials and articles are on how to dockerize simple springboot applications or springboot applications that use only one database, thus any input on how I can proceed to dockerize my application would be really appreciated!

I am following this tutorial -
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/running-a-multi-container-springboot-postgresql-application-with-docker-compose/

Here in the docker-compose.yml file-

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  API:
    image: 'blog-api-docker.jar'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      PostgreSQL:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  PostgreSQL:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

Only one postgreSQL datasource is defined ,in my project with a similar postgreSQL datasource as given in the tutorial I am also using a mongoDB database which is running on atlas.
I am also including my application.properties file for your reference-

```
    spring.ds-psql.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/devicestatspsql
    spring.ds-psql.datasource.username=
    spring.ds-psql.datasource.password=
    
    spring.data.mongodb.users-mongo-atlas.uri=*mongodb database url here*

    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

So I just need to know what changes are required in my docker-compose.yml file to accommodate this mongodb database in the docker image

Comment: "So I just need to know what changes are required in my docker-compose.yml file to accommodate this mongodb database in the docker image" => I think that you are facing a problem because there is a misconception with your targetted architecture. You will not add mongoDB in one of the docker images already defined, you just need to run three containers, one for your application, one for PostgreSQL, one for MongoDB. So you need to add another service to your docker-compose file to create the mongodb container, and then reference it in your application configuration. Is this OK for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , and yes finally was able to make it work, although I didnt make any additional container for the mongodb and still it worked, I guess because the mongodb was running in atlas thats why we didnt have to create a separate container for it?? I m still learning and have no idea how this worked